# How do you call a method using only some of its parameters?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to pass string from text boxes to a method in the same class, yet when i try to do so i get an error message:

`no overload method, TotalWeighting takes one argument.`

Despite having include  each object in the parameters of the method im trying to send to. The error message appears around where calling the method.

Here is a bit of the bottom of the program:

```
public void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{//Assignment 6, box 1
    string STRtb11 = textBox7.Text;//Get value from textBox7 and set to new varaible STRtb10
    TotalWeighting(STRtb11);
}

public void textBox12_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{//Assignment 6, box 2
    string STRtb12 = textBox12.Text;//Get value from textBox12 and set to new varaible STRtb11
    TotalWeighting(STRtb12);
}

public static double TotalWeighting(string STRtb1, string STRtb2, string STRtb3, string STRtb4, string STRtb5, string STRtb6, string STRtb7, string STRtb8, string STRtb9, string STRtb10, string STRtb12)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, compiler seems to be right. `TotalWeighting` accepts 12 arguments (which is a really bad thing to do).

Comment: Im trying to send it 12, just from different events

Comment: You should spend some time learning basic programming principles: [Parameter (computer programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method `TotalWeighting` accepts 12 strings, and in its current form cannot accept anything less.

There are several options to improve this method:

1. You can pass `null` for each string that you do not use, and handle these nulls in the method:

   `TotalWeighting("alpha", "bravo", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);`
2. You can use default parameters by changing the method signature to:

   ```
   public static double TotalWeighting(
       string STRtb1 = null,
       string STRtb2 = null,
       string STRtb3 = null,
       string STRtb4 = null,
       string STRtb5 = null,
       string STRtb6 = null,
       string STRtb7 = null,
       string STRtb8 = null,
       string STRtb9 = null,
       string STRtb10 = null,
       string STRtb12 = null)
   {
       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. You can overload the method for each desired number of arguments:

   ```
   public static double TotalWeighting(string STRtb1) { ... }
   public static double TotalWeighting(string STRtb1, string STRtb2) { ... }
    ...
   ```
4. You can use the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword to allow the method to accept a variable number of parameters:

   ```
   public static double TotalWeighting(params string[] input) { ... }
   ```

Comment: Although this will let the program compile, I doubt that this is help OP achieve what he actually needs (which is, I presume, to dynamically calculate a value depending on 12 different values, whenever one of them changes).

Answer (score 0):

Your `TotalWeighting` method requires *12 arguments* `STRtb1..STRtb12`; so you should either provide these 12 arguments or implement a function with 1 argument only:

```
// Leave 1 argument of 12 ones
public static double TotalWeighting(string STRtb1) {
  return 0;
}
```