# Is it okay to pass null/empty unused parameters to a method?

Tags: java, function, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm trying to find what is the best practice to do in a similar case, say I have a method

```
String getContent(String id, Boolean remove_tags) {
    …
}
```

This has a long implementation, and I need the functionality but in some cases I don't want to send the second parameter, is the right practice for this case to pass it as **null** or to create a another method with only the first parameter and make that method return this one this way:

```
String getContent(String id) {
     return getContent(id, null);
}
```

I've read a suggestion in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205492/how-do-you-call-a-method-using-only-some-of-its-parameters#:%7E:text=You%20can%20pass,null%2C%20null%2C%20null)%3B) to only pass it as a null.

I might be making a big deal of *nothing*, but I've tried to make a couple researches about such a topic and couldn't find something useful, so I need some opinions please about this!

Comment: what's the problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: So if you pass `null`, does it remove tags or not? Not very clean design. Tri-state booleans should be avoided like the plague in the first place, so this has more issues than just passing a `null`.

Comment: Sorry if the question is not clear enough, the Boolean was just an example for a second parameter, but just to imagine that a method have several parameters, and I can get the functionality I need of it by passing only some of its parameters, is the right thing to do here to pass the others as null/empty or create a another method with the parameters I need only?
@Kayaman

Comment: If the choice is between passing null as a default value or cloning and duplicating (potentially a lot of) code I would rather chose passing null. That being said as everything in programming it should be done in moderation and if at some point you end up having a call like `getContent(id, null, null, null, null, null, null);` you probably overdid it and should rethink your method design ;)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS
It's kind of a legacy code, sure refactoring is an option, if not the best, but just wanted to know some opinions about such case.

Comment: I tried editing the Question’s body to make that shown URL a link. But I failed. Can anyone spot what is causing the Stack Overflow site’s renderer to not hide the URL?

Comment: @BasilBourque It's the parenthesis in the URL's search string URI that needed to be escaped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either way is allowed. I have seen both used, even within the libraries bundled with Java.

## Prefer overloading

```
String getContent( String id , Boolean remove_tags ) { … }
String getContent( String id ) { … }
```

Adding the second method with a single parameter has the benefit of clearly **communicating that a single argument will succeed**.

With only the first method, the calling programmer cannot tell if passing a null for the second argument is allowed. She would have to study the Javadoc, or perhaps even the source code, to determine if a null will succeed.

[Self-documenting code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code) is generally preferable.

By the way, the technical term for adding methods that share a name is [*overloading*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).